# Angular 14 how to use async pipe with specific field in json response?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, subscribe

Hello friendly early birds!

I fetch data from an API with following response:

[image]

My service returns the Observable<Movie[]> object to my component. In the HTML of the component, I want to use the async pipe instead of subscription.
So I don't have to unsub on the components to prevent memory leaks.

**movie-list.component.html:**

```
<div class="movie-list">
  <div class="movie-element" *ngFor="let movie of movies$ | async">
    <app-movie
      [movie]="movie"
    ></app-movie>
  </div>
</div>
```

**movie-list.component.ts:**

```
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {

  movies$!: Observable<Movie[]>;

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movies$ = this.movieService.getMostPopularMovies();
  }
}
```

**movie-service.ts:**

```
})
export class MovieService {

  private apiKey: string = environment.apiKey;
  private apiMostPopularMovies: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMostPopularMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('api_key', this.apiKey);

    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.apiMostPopularMovies, {params});
  }
}
```

**Movie.component.ts:**

```
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() movie!: Movie;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

My Movie model just have a title, poster_path and vote_average field. The field have the same names as the the response in results array have. I don't need anything else from the response.

Somehow I have to map the fields from the response from results array to my Movie model. Can someone explain how to do this with async pipe?

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is here, your code looks good. I would expect `movies$` to contain `Observable<Movie[]>` and then each instance of `<app-movie>` will correctly receive a `movie` object of type `Movie`. What do you need to map? Do you mean that the API objects contain more fields than `title`, `poster_path` and `vote_average`, in which case `Observable<Movie[]>` would instead be `Observable<FullMovie[]>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is your response actually is not `Movie[]` but your `response.results` is.

To solve this, you could use `map` operator in rxjs. If you could use the following code in your service, async pipe would work fine.

```
export class MovieService {

  private apiKey: string = environment.apiKey;
  private apiMostPopularMovies: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMostPopularMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('api_key', this.apiKey);

    return this.http
               .get<{results: Movie[]}>(this.apiMostPopularMovies, {params})
               .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions works. I had a similar approach bevor with the pipe and map but I forgot the generic type declaration for results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can try this in your service:

```
mappedMoviesObs: Observable<Movies[]> = this.getMostPopularMovies().pipe(
  map((movies: Movies[]) => movies.forEach((movie) => { // do mapping})
);
```

And in html use `mappedMoviesObs` instead of `movies$`.